# Counting SQL Select Rows. Count = 0 where it should be 1

Tags: php, sql

```
      $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM superhidden WHERE username = '$username' AND  password='$password'");



      $credentials = mysql_num_rows($result);

      echo $credentials;
```

This echoes 0!!! When $username = admin and $password = admin... and the supperhidden table contains a row admin | admin

Comment: Are you storing your passwords in plain text?

Comment: `superhidden` --- such secure, wow

Comment: **Note:** naming your table `superhidden`, doesn't actually make it more hidden.

Comment: @zerkms damn you beat me to it!

Comment: yes plaintext storing

Comment: Counting down to mandatory *'please do not use `mysql_` functions, they're deprecated'* replies.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes: it's annoying isn't it?

Comment: @zerkms I'm just now doubting whether I annoyed myself by actually still saying it...

Comment: Try `var_dump( $username, $password );`

Comment: I can't wait to type my password as  `'; truncate superhidden -- `

Comment: @Arian: and nothing destructive will happen :-)

Comment: @Arian just [name your son Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd check is for leading or trailing spaces in both the table columns and the `$username/$password` variables.

You can examine leading or trailing spaces in the DB with something like:

```
select    *
  from    superhidden
 where    username like ' %'
    or    username like '% '
    or    password like ' %'
    or    password like '% '
```

You can use [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/var_dump) for examining the variables.

---

And, of course, the near-obligatory remarks on almost *all* PHP/MySQL questions:

- The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should be using one of the [newer APIs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
- Use of user input without sanitisation is a bad idea. You should make sure both `$username` and `$password` cannot be used for SQL injection attacks. Search for [parameterised queries](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=parameterised%20queries) or [SQL injection](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sql%20injection) for more detail.

It's also generally a bad idea to store passwords in plain text, as evidenced by the rather large number of data "thefts", the latest of which was Target in the USA with some 70 million customers affected. There's a good QA [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords) which provides some guidance.

Comment: More a comment than an answer?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, no, I'm positing that as an answer. If it turns out to be wrong, I'll delete it. Comments are meant for clarifications and tangential stuff, like arguing about deprecated features and SQL injection :-)

Comment: +1'd. Last thing: as soon as you added the obligatory remarks section - a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords or something similar might be helpful

Comment: It turned out I used $username = "something else" up further on the page which made it read the wrong username from the table..